# How to make doxygen include namespace members to group page

Tags: c++, namespaces, grouping, doxygen

I need to get a list of all classes (and other elements) at doxygen group page even if they are namespace members.
So if I have something like this code example:

```
/*!
@defgroup test_group Example group
@{*/
    class some_class {};
/// @}
```

Doxygen will generate group page, containing my "some_class" :

[image: page with class].

But after namespace adding doxygen "hides" all namespace members to new page. Next code:

```
/*!
@defgroup test_group Example group
@{*/
namespace example_namespace {       
    class some_class {};
}
/// @}
```

produces a group page, containing link to namespace page.

[image: 2 step navigation].

We can't see namespace members on group page.

Next 2 ways gives the same result:

```
// 1. putting namespace content in brackets @{ @}:
    /// @defgroup test_group Example group        
    namespace example_namespace { 
        /*!
        @ingroup test_group 
        @{ */
        class some_class {};
        /// @}
    }        
// 2. putting namespace itself to group:

    /// @defgroup test_group Example group

    /// @ingroup test_group 
    namespace example_namespace {
        class some_class {};
    }
```

I want to get a group page, that will contain all classes from namespaces and namespaces themselves. I know that adding  "`@ingroup`" to class description gives me what I want, but in real program there are tens or even hundreds of classes in one namespace. There must be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

I did some small tests and the following works:

```
/*!
@defgroup test_group Example group
@{*/
namespace example_namespace {
    /*!
    @defgroup test_group Example group
    @{*/
    /** the class */
    class some_class {
      /*!
      @defgroup test_group Example group
      @{*/
      public:
         /** the fie */
         void fie(void);
      /// @}
    };
    /// @}
};
/// @}
```

It is a bit overhead, and maybe you also should look at the other `group` commands like `\ingroup`, `\addtogroup` and the paragraph about grouping in the manual.

Comment: So it was the question how to avoid thousands of "copy-paste" in a huge project. :)

Comment: OK I see, missed the last paragraph of the question. I think you only have to add the `\ingroup` once per file where the classes are defined in the namespace and maybe it is sufficient (didn't test it), to create an (extra)  `.h` file with just the namespace and class names and the appropriate groups.